# How to add scroll only for one template

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm new in frontend and just have started to learn Vue + Quasar Framework. So, I have a table and want to fix my table name and scroll is only available in my table items.

```
<template>
    <q-table
      virtual-scroll
      class="fit"
      :style="'overflow: hidden;'"
    >
      <template v-slot:top >
        <div>Fruits</div>
        <q-space />
        <q-btn icon="search"/>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:fruit="props">
        <div class="q-pa-xs col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            // my items cards
        </div>
      </template>

      
    </q-table>
 

</template>
<style>
.fit

  .q-table__top,
  .q-table__bottom,
  thead tr:first-child th
    /* bg color is important for th; just specify one */

  thead tr th
    position: sticky
    z-index: 1
  thead tr:first-child th
    top: 0
  /* this is when the loading indicator appears */
  &.q-table--loading thead tr:last-child th
    top: 48px
</style>
```

Comment: the [Quasar docs](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#sticky-header-column) recommend just using CSS, namely `position: sticky`.

Comment: Don't want to work. Maybe the problem is in scroll class of Quasar Page?

Comment: Or maybe because of templates inside q-table?

Comment: "Don't want to work" isn't enough information to provide help.  Add what code you tried to your question.  There's no special Vue/Quasar code needed to make an element sticky since it's just CSS.  Did you view the source code in the docs for the sticky header example and add the same CSS?

Comment: I've copy code from your link, it works perfectly fine in row mode, but in grid isn't. Maybe you now why? Because even in Quasar docks I don't find information about how to "pin" table header in grid mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rendered table elements are not designed/organized the same way in grid mode as in row mode.  Inspecting the DOM in the browser shows q-table in row mode has a standard table with header and body

```html
<div
  class="q-table__container q-table--horizontal-separator column no-wrap q-table__card q-table--no-wrap my-sticky-header-table"
>
  <div class="q-table__top relative-position row items-center">...</div>
  <div
    class="q-table__middle q-virtual-scroll q-virtual-scroll--vertical scroll"
  >
    <table class="q-table">
      <!-- table header -->
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-left sortable">...</th>
          <th class="text-center sortable">...</th>
          <th class="text-right sortable">...</th>
          <th class="text-right">Carbs (g)</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <!-- table content -->
      <tbody class="q-virtual-scroll__padding">...</tbody>
      <tbody class="q-virtual-scroll__content" tabindex="-1">...</tbody>
      <tbody class="q-virtual-scroll__padding">...</tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which is why a sticky header row requires `position: sticky; top: 0;` applied to the `<th>` elements

```
  thead tr th
    position: sticky
    z-index: 1
  thead tr:first-child th
    top: 0
```

In grid mode, there is no `<table>` used to organize the grid elements

```html
<div
  class="q-table__container q-table--horizontal-separator column no-wrap q-table--grid q-table--no-wrap my-sticky-header-table"
>
  <div class="q-table__top relative-position row items-center">...</div>
  <div class="q-table__middle">
    <table class="q-table">
      <!-- table header -->
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-left sortable">...</th>
          <th class="text-center sortable">...</th>
          <th class="text-right sortable">...</th>
          <th class="text-right">Carbs (g)</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- grid content -->
  <div class="q-table__grid-content row">
    <div class="q-table__grid-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">...</div>
    <div class="q-table__grid-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">...</div>
    <div class="q-table__grid-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">...</div>
    <div class="q-table__grid-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">...</div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

You see there is a `<table>` but it only contains the header information. The grid content is completely separate.  Because of that, you don't need to sticky anything.  Just give the grid content a height and `overflow: auto` which will add a scrollbar to the grid and the table header information will remain positioned on top.

```
.q-table__grid-content
  height: 310px
  overflow: auto
```

[working sandbox example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasarframework-webpack-tjcznm?file=src%2Fpages%2FIndexPage.vue)